# Can't edit Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, bundle

Apple reject my app because I choose appid with In-app purchase but I don't use it. So I created wildcart id with com.domain.*. But ı can't use it. Please help. Thank you.

I download my provisioning profile. And trying to drop over the project in XCode. But the Bundle identifier doesn't change.

My app id is com.domain.*
In Xcode bundle identifier is com.domain.appname.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the info tab of your Target, change your bundle identifier. The wildcard simply means that you can use *any* value, not just an asterisk. For example, `com.myappcompany.ourfirstapp` is a valid identifier for the `com.myappcompany.*` identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to info tab in Target of your application and change bundle identifier from there.

[image]